# DataGridViewComboBoxCell selectioindexchange event

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a data-grid and three column in it. one column is type of DataGridViewComboBoxCell, three items are in this grid combo box, now i have to invoke selection index changed event to change value according to combo value change in grid.

also help me to make a new event ....

please help...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I really can't understand your question.

But maybe these informations can help:

A ComboBoxColumn has always two kinds of controls. A presenting one (in most cases a label) which is individually for each row. And a editing one that will be shared for the whole column. So take a look into [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx) and the [IDataGridViewEditingControl Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.idatagridvieweditingcontrol.aspx).

Maybe these will give you a starting point on how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the Load event for the form, you need to get the cell that you want to add the handler to and cast it as a regular combo box.  You can then add the event handler on `SelectedIndexChanged`, but it must be done programmatically, and depending on the language you are using.